# downloading images using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to download images using the below code and got a error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import re 
import urllib 
import urllib.request as ur 
import os 
import http.cookiejar as cookielib 
import json

def get_soup(url,header):
    return BeautifulSoup(ur.urlopen(ur.Request(url,headers=header)),'html.parser')


query = 'apple'   #you can change the query for the image  here
image_type="ActiOn" query= query.split() query='+'.join(query)
url="https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
print (url)
#add the directory for your image here 
DIR="/Users/jashuvadoma/Desktop/hacking/images"
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"} 
soup = get_soup(url,header)


ActualImages=[] # contains the link for Large original images, type of image 
for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):
    link , Type =json.loads(a.text)["ou"], json.loads(a.text)["ity"]
    ActualImages.append((link,Type))
print ("there are total" , len(ActualImages),"images")

if not os.path.exists(DIR):
    os.mkdir(DIR) DIR = os.path.join(DIR, query.split()[0])

if not os.path.exists(DIR):
    os.mkdir(DIR)
###print images 
for i , (img , Type) in enumerate( ActualImages):
    try:
        req = ur.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent' : header})
        raw_img = ur.urlopen(req).read()
        cntr = lea([i for i in os.listdir(DIR) if image_type in i]) + 1
        print (cntr)
        if len(Type)==0:
            f = open(os.path.join(DIR , image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+".jpg"), 'wb')
        else :
            f = open(os.path.join(DIR , image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+"."+Type), 'wb')
        f.write(raw_img)
        f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print ("could not load : "+img)
        print (e)
```

Error as follows:
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=apple&source=lnms&tbm=isch
there are total 100 images
could not load : https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201606271147
expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Please format your code -it isn't readable like this.

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly indicates that some parameter need to a string value but something else is passed.

Before posting a question you should try to debug it by yourself. Few things you can try:

1. Don't catch too broad exceptions. With proper exception handling, you can easily trace:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1278 
   1279         for hdr, value in headers.items():
-> 1280             self.putheader(hdr, value)
   1281         if isinstance(body, str):
   1282             # RFC 2616 Section 3.7.1 says that text default has a

/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in putheader(self, header, *values)
   1214                 values[i] = str(one_value).encode('ascii')
   1215 
-> 1216             if _is_illegal_header_value(values[i]):
   1217                 raise ValueError('Invalid header value %r' % (values[i],))
   1218 

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Now looking at the trace it seems that an header value is wrong.

2. Adding proper log statements. Logging the header value it appeared to be a dict rather than string.

In print images section change headers as follows:

```
req = ur.Request(img, headers=header)
```